# How do you enable "Display Zoom" mode in SwiftUI preview?

Tags: swiftui, accessibility

How do you enable "Display Zoom" mode in SwiftUI preview?

On a phone, you get to it from Settings, Display & Brightness, Display Zoom. Choose Standard or Zoomed.

On the simulator you can set it from Settings, Developer, Display Zoom.

But I don't see a way to set this in SwiftUI preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, many iOS features are not usable in a SwiftUI canvas preview. Display Zoom is one of them.